# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ndim' [Python | Keras]

Tags: python, keras, recurrent-neural-network, attributeerror

below is my code which is mostly the same as the code found here: https://keras.io/examples/generative/lstm_character_level_text_generation/

It has worked for one day going through all epochs, however, today it runs but errors out at random epochs with the AttributeError error saying that string doesn't have the ndim attribute which makes no sense as the data being inputted and converted into a numpy array from lines 51-56 is the same as before when it worked, so how is it changing this data to be a string? And how has this changed over the course of a day with no tampering of the input data or code for taking in the data.

```
def load_file(self, filename):
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    content = file.read()
    file.close()
    return content

def sample(self, preds, temperature=1.0):
    preds = np.asarray(preds).astype("float64")
    preds = np.log(preds) / temperature
    exp_preds = np.exp(preds)
    preds = exp_preds / np.sum(exp_preds)
    probas = np.random.multinomial(1, preds, 1)
    return np.argmax(probas)
    

def train(self, epochs, batch_size):
    content = self.load_file("data/ABC_cleaned/input.txt")

    chars = sorted(list(set(content)))
    char_indices = dict((c, i) for i, c in enumerate(chars))
    indices_char = dict((i, c) for i, c in enumerate(chars))

    maxlen = 40
    step = 3
    sentences = []
    next_chars = []
    for i in range(0, len(content) - maxlen, step):
        sentences.append(content[i:i+maxlen])
        next_chars.append(content[i+maxlen])

    x = np.zeros((len(sentences), maxlen, len(chars)), dtype=np.bool)
    y = np.zeros((len(sentences), len(chars)), dtype=np.bool)
    for i, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
        for t, char in enumerate(sentence):
            x[i, t, char_indices[char]] = 1
        y[i, char_indices[next_chars[i]]] = 1
    print(type(x))
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(input_layer.InputLayer(input_shape=(maxlen, len(chars))))
    model.add(layers.LSTM(128))
    model.add(layers.Dense(len(chars), activation='softmax'))
    optimizer = optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.01)
    model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=optimizer)
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        model.fit(x, y, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=1)
        print()
        print("Generating text after epoch %d" % epoch)

        start_index = np.random.randint(0, len(content) -maxlen - 1)
        for diversity in [0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 1.2]:
            print("...Diversity:", diversity)

            generated = ""
            sentence = content[start_index:start_index+maxlen]
            print('...Generating with seed: "' + sentence + '"')

            for i in range(400):
                x_pred = np.zeros((1, maxlen, len(chars)))
                for t, char in enumerate(sentence):
                    x_pred[0, t, char_indices[char]] = 1.0
                preds = model.predict(x_pred, verbose=0)[0]
                next_index = self.sample(preds, diversity)
                next_char = indices_char[next_index]
                sentence = sentence[1:] + next_char
                generated += next_char
            print("...Generated: ", generated)
            print()
            topSeven = []
            contentSong = []
            fullAbc = ""
            count = 0
            if "X:" in generated:
                index = generated.find("X:")
                generated = generated[index:]
                genList = generated.split('\n')
                for line in genList:
                    if count > 6:
                        if line and generated[count+1]:
                            contentSong.append(line)
                        else:
                            contentSong.append(line)
                            break
                    if line.startswith(("X:", "T:", "%", "S:", "M:", "L:", "K:")):
                        topSeven.append(line)
                        count+=1
                if len(topSeven) == 7:
                    for x in topSeven:
                        fullAbc += x + "\n"
                    for x in contentSong:
                        fullAbc += x + "\n"
                    with open("good_reels.txt", 'a') as f:
                        f.write("\n" + fullAbc)
                        f.close()
                    break
```

Comment: What's the line that's giving this error?

Comment: Im pretty sure it happens at model.fit however, the AttributeError happens within the training_utils.py within keras. But it makes no sense as it does run multiple times before doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring `x` twice in this code. First here

```py
x = np.zeros((len(sentences), maxlen, len(chars)), dtype=np.bool)
y = np.zeros((len(sentences), len(chars)), dtype=np.bool)
```

and second here:

```py
if len(topSeven) == 7:
    for x in topSeven:
        fullAbc += x + "\n"
    for x in contentSong:
        fullAbc += x + "\n"
    with open("good_reels.txt", 'a') as f:
        f.write("\n" + fullAbc)
        f.close()
    break
```

In the first loop iteration, `x` is indeed a `numpy.ndarray` and it'll work as expected. When it reaches the second declaration, `x` is now a `str` and it'll also work as expected.

In the second loop iteration, `x` is currently a `str` when it expected a `numpy.ndarray`, and it'll give the error.

To fix it, just rename the second declaration of `x` to `c`, for example, or even remove the loop it's being declared:

```py
if len(topSeven) == 7:
    fullAbc += '\n'.join(topSeven)
    fullAbc += '\n'.join(contentSong)
    with open("good_reels.txt", 'a') as f:
        f.write("\n" + fullAbc)
        f.close()
    break
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have fixed it. Very weird though, I thought the x's within the for loops were local to them but I guess I just misunderstood where the scope of each x was.